# How to limit the maximum size read via ObjectInputStream from a Socket?

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, stream

Is there a way to limit the maximum buffer size to be read from an ObjectInputStream in java?

I want to stop the deserialization if it becomes clear that the Object in question is crafted maliciously huge.

Of course, there is ObjectInputStream.read(byte[] buf, int off, int len), but I do not want to suffer the performance penalty of allocating, say byte[1000000].

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You write a [`FilterInputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html) which will throw an exception if it discovers it has read more than a certain amount of data from its underlying stream.

Comment: Tanky you very much! Very nice wrapper!

Answer (score 2):

I can see two ways:
1) do your reads in a loop, grabbing chunks whose allocation size you're comfortable with, and exit and stop when you hit your limit; or
2) Allocate your max-size buffer once and re-use it for subsequent reads.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will use No. 1 and try to wrap it in Jon Skeets FilterInputStream suggestion.

Comment: You're welcome.  **Jon Skeet**'s answer is superior, imo.  They're equivalent from a "what happens" perspective, but `FilterInputStream` is much clearer and more standard.  Less wheel-reinvention.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's a really easy way.

You can use NIO's ByteBuffer, and use the allocateDirect method. This method will allow you to allocate a memory-mapped file, so it doesn't have a huge overhead, and you can limit its size.

Then, instead of getting the stream from the socket, get the Channel.

Code:

```
    Socket s;

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(10 * 1024 * 1024);
    s.getChannel().read(buffer);
```

Now, don't try to call the "array()" method on the byte buffer; it doesn't work on a directly-allocated buffer. However, you can [wrap the buffer as an input stream](http://exampledepot.com/egs/java.nio/Buffer2Stream.html) and send it to the ObjectInputStream for further processing.