# Is there a restriction on the amount of text I can write / read with a stream writer / reader in C#?

Tags: c#, stream, filestream, streamreader, streamwriter

I am trying to write to some text file using a stream writer. 
the text I am trying to write is from a different text file.

I try:

```
string line = reader.ReadLine(); //reader is a streamReader I defined before
while (line != null)
{
    sw.WriteLine(line); //sw is a streamWriter I defined before
    line = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

I also tried:

```
while (!(reader.EndOfStream))
{
    sw.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine()); //sw is a streamWriter I defined before
}
```

this two methods succeeded to copy the text from the file to the other file, but from some reason not all of the text was copied. 
The text file I am trying to copy from is very large, about 96000 lines, and only the ~95000 first lines are copied.

Therfore, I am asking if there is a restriction on the amount of text I can write / read with a stream writer / reader in C#?

Also, I asking for some suggestions for how to succeed copy all the text.
(I read that there is a method copy of the Stream class, but that is for .NET4, so it wont help).

**EDIT:** I tried to replace the text in the end that didn't copied by a text form the start that was copied. I got the same problem, so it isn't a problem with the characters.

Comment: I had the same thought, there may be some odd binary characters in the source file causing premature termination.

Comment: There is definately a limit based on how much RAM you have, but I dont know off hand what c# limits your buffer size to.  I would also point you to here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249475/how-to-limit-the-maximum-size-read-via-objectinputstream-from-a-socket .

Comment: How do you know that not every line was copied? Are you just comparing file sizes, or have you used a diff tool?

Comment: Those are text files. I just opened them with notepad++ and compared by what I see.

Comment: Please see my edit in the question.

Comment: Jim: The RAM not necessart will limit this. In modern operating systems (exept some real-time operating systems) there is a mechanism called paging. Paging let you use the disk as he was RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm. Probably you are not flushing your stream. Try doing sw.Autoflush=true; Or, before you close sw, call sw.Flush();

Comment: thank you. The problem was that I didn't close the stream. I add the close and it solved it. After it I added the flush and it also work fine. What accactly the flush doing?

Comment: To make the writes more efficient, the stream will not necessarily immediately write to disk everytime YOU call Write. It will buffer the writes in memory and then it the buffer is large enough it writes them to disk at one time. Calling flush makes sure that the writes make it to disk. Of course, calling close may very well also write all the bytes to disk, but that's not necessarily guaranteed.

Comment: Thank you. So, if I understood you right, it is always better to flush? or that sometimes from some reason it is better not using it? I mean beside the efficiency

Comment: You should always call it before you close your stream. Or, as I said you can set Autoflush to true, and then everytime you write, it also calls flush for you. As far as I know besides efficiency there is no other reason, except perhaps the possibility that you HAVE to have your writes immediately be flushed to disk because it is mission critical software.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess that you are not calling flush on your output stream.  This would cause the last few (sometimes a lot) of lines to not be written to the output file.

Comment: Sometimes I think you should be able to see what other people are typing as you are typing your answer. :). When I saw your answer after posting mine, I actually thought for a second I double posted. :)